# Построчное декодирование текстового файла

Tags: base64, php

Здравствуйте. Как построчно обработать текстовый файл, закодированный в base64? Файл имеет следующий вид:

1. MTMwNzY5
2. OTAzNjk4OTI2Mw==
3. dXNlcjEyMw==
4. ZWdvcjIwMDA=
5. MTAwMDAwMA==
6. MTIzMzIx

Пробовал код

```
<?php 
    $file = file('src.txt'); 
    for ($i=1; $i<99999; $i++) { 
        echo base64_decode($file[$i]);
    }
?>
```

Но он выводит всё в одну строку. Как сделать, чтобы выводило построчно (или на экран или в файл)?

Comment: ``echo PHP_EOL;``

Comment: У вас в файле 99999 строчек или это такая элегантная замена ``count()`` или ``foreach``?

Answer (score 3):

```
{ echo base64_decode($file[$i]).PHP_EOL; }
```

Если вывод идет в браузер - обернуть все целиком в `<pre>`

Comment: @Fike, подозреваю, что для ТС нужен еще один совет -- погуглить

     php размер массива

Answer (score 3):

[@avp](/users/232/avp), а я на Java попробую :)

```
String[] dataToDecode = input.split("\n");
for (String decoding : dataToDecode) {
    System.out.println(new String(Base64.decode(decoding, Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8"));
}
```

Сейчас попробую запустить свой ужас, вдруг сработает.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку метка *php* не указана, рискну развлечься на шелле.

Набиваем s.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
file=$1
while read a 
do
    t=`echo $a | base64 -d`
    echo $t
done < $file
```

и запускаем

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./s.sh src.txt
130769
9036989263
user123
egor2000
1000000
123321
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```